# How to safely remove files from master which have already been removed from a branch?

Tags: git, git-rm

Refer to the following diagram:

```
my-branch      A---B---C---D
              /     \
master       E---F---G
```

During the merge from `B` to `G` I have inadvertently added files to `master` which I deleted from `my-branch` at `D` using `git rm`. Unfortunately, I have work at `C` which is not yet ready to be merged with master. Can I safely `git rm` the files in `master` and still merge `my-branch` (where the files have already been deleted) into `master` later?

In other words, by merging `B` with `G`, I added files to master at commit `G` which I do not want. These files are `git rm`'d  from `my-branch` at `D`, but I do not want to merge `D` into master because `C` contains changes that are not ready yet. What is the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the D commit only has the rm'ed files then I would move it ahead of the C commit, then merge that into master.

In this case that would be `git rebase -i HEAD~2` then reorder the commits to put D before C. You can then merge D into master and end up with

`A---B---D---C
 /         \
E---F---G---H`

If D has other changes, then you should redo the commit so it only has the rm'ed files, and then reorder them.

If you've already published `my-branch` then anyone who has pulled it will end up with a merge containing existing changes from `C` and `D`. In that case I would cherry-pick `D` onto master in order to get the files deleted prior to merging `my-branch` and then deal with a trivial merge conflict when you do merge into `master`. IMO it would be better for you to deal with the conflict once later, rather than everyone else deal with it now.

Comment: So... what if I have published `my-branch` up through commit `D`? Would this cause any headaches down the road by re-writing history? EDIT: perhaps it would be okay, since D only contains rm'ed files...

Comment: Edited my answer for that case. If anyone else has that branch, then you'll end up creating weird merges for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unfamiliar or uncomfortable using interactive rebase, you could create a branch at commit G and cherry-pick D. Then pr or merge your branch into master.